# How to implement a manual security procedure with Django

Tags: django, security, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

I'm writing a web application with Django framework. This web application is API based and I'm using Django rest_framework. I have a security issue: On the first page, the user must solve a Recaptcha. After solving the Recaptcha my site gives a session ID to the user and after this, the user must post this session ID in the body of all his/her API calls and every API can be called just once with a specific session ID. In other words, I have a state machine for the APIs being called by the user and in each state, the user can call the APIs which have corresponding outgoing edges from that state.

**The purpose of all of the above procedures is preventing the user from crawling my website. (User can't call an API many times with a session ID and he/she should act as a normal user and call every API at most two or three times)**

Now my question is that how should I handle this in my Django app? Before this, I just used the ordinary Django session middleware for handling sessions. Now should I handle the authentication process and passing and getting session ID completely in a manual way or is there a way in which I can use that middleware that it can be able to handle my procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with simply with saving your user's state and in each step update your user's state and consider the next states which user can see.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom permission classes for your APIViews to block such request.
Read more here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions